# Error in generate app package in UWP ERROR: MCG0037

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, wns

I have an error when I'm going to generate the package, before it was working, but when I implemented a background task and went to generate the package, this error appeared, does anyone know what it can be?

```
MCG0037: MCG0037:InvalidCSharpIdentifierName Struct '_MI_ClientFT_V1' in assembly 'Assembly(Name=Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)' has a field with name '<alignment member>' that is invalid.
This could be because the name is obfuscated or the field is auto-implemented by the compiler. Please make sure the field name follows C# identifier conventions.
```

Comment: You need check your out process background task entry point and give it a rule name .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by removing some packages I wasn't using